# 15.04 upgrade issue upstart

Tags: server, upstart, 15.04, dbus, systemd

ah I feel like an idiot! So I decided to upgrade my distro (like a dummy because I am hosting something for a school assignment) on an openVZ server. Now I can't get systemd working.

I get the following message whenever I try to start any services:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory`

Originally I was getting `"xdg_runtime_dir" wasn't set, set it to tmp.`

I have also got the following:

```
Failed to make us a subreaper: Invalid argument Perhaps the kernel version is too old (< 3.4?)
Assertion 'clock_gettime(clock_id, &ts) == 0' failed at src/shared/time-util.c:34, function now(). Aborting.
```

I'm running `2.6.32-04stab093.5` which is probably the problem (version that came with the VM).

So, the obvious thing would be to disable systemd...well since it's in emergency mode, and I can't get any of the services to run, I'm pretty much screwed. I checked this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

It wasn't particularly helpful because I can do the one time...except I don't have grub! Can't install grub because no network. Can't install the permanent solution either, because of same lack of network connectivity!

Since it's a virtual server, I don't have physical access, so no boot cd or pen drive.

I have a case open with the VM provider to see if they can pull a back up of my files, but I'm not optimistic.

So my friends, do any of you have recommendations for this poor fool who stupidly upgraded? If I can find a solution that will at least get me connected to the internet, I think I can get around this evilness?

Thank you for your time and consideration! I would greatly appreciate any assistance!